# Setting TAB to 2 spaces

Tags: whitespace, tab-characters

I've looked through various answers which imply that setting the following in `.vimrc` would be appropriate to force tab insertions to become spaces.

```
filetype plugin indent on
" On pressing tab, insert 2 spaces
set expandtab
" show existing tab with 2 spaces width
set tabstop=2
set softtabstop=2
" when indenting with '>', use 2 spaces width
set shiftwidth=2
```

However, when I attempt to use 2 spaces, it continues to default to 4 spaces per tab. I have tried moving `set expandtab` to the bottom of these declarations. I have tried removing the `softtabstop` declaration. I've scoured the various answers given to other questions as well.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Have you sourced your `.vimrc` since making these changes? When having vim open just type `source ~/.vimrc` (assuming it is in it's default location)

EDIT: [This could help too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878974/redefine-tab-as-4-spaces)

Comment: It looks like my problem was indeed a lack of sourcing. I had read that the file would be automatically sourced when you edited it, and indeed I did see some changes to my VIM when initially creating the .vimrc file. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Gleland, Is there a way to only set `tabs` to 2 spaces, for markdown files only?

Comment: @alpha_989 this should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158968/changing-vim-indentation-behavior-by-file-type#159066

Answer (score 1):

This should fix your problem. It has more options, but two first lines are most important.

```
set tabstop=2 softtabstop=2 shiftwidth=2
set expandtab
set number ruler
set autoindent smartindent
syntax enable
filetype plugin indent on
```

Comment: Can you explain what this does and how it solves a problem that OP solved 6 years ago?

Comment: "two first lines are most important" - you could easily improve your answer if you removed the other lines.